# Gravity Forms to Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, gravity-forms-plugin

I am getting this error

Unable to authenticate LiveId.

http://prntscr.com/cx116z

Comment: The thing supports up to CRM Online 2015, what's the version of your CRM Online ?

Comment: I signed up for Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online, how can I find the version?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to get in touch with developers of that application. It looks like you use Office 365 authentication and that application tries to authenticate using provided credentials using LiveId that is not used as authentication provider for years.

Comment: LiveID Auth works in CRM Online (or rather, is supported by Office365)

Comment: So in other words you want to say that xxx@yyy.onmicrosoft.com is LiveId account? :)

Comment: I meant that "LiveId that is not used as authentication provider" is an inaccurate statement.

Comment: It still works but number of LiveId - auth orgs is less then 50 worldwide (according to Microsoft) that means that this authentication provider potentially will be deprecated. Based on account provided I assume that user's org uses Office 365 Authentication. Based on the message I assume that LiveId authentication is used that causes an exception that leads to my initial suggestion to get in touch with developers of application to get support.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what plugin you are using, but our plugin fully supports Office 365 Authentication and works fully with CRM On-Premises and CRM Online versions 2011 or later: https://www.saintsystems.com/products/gravity-forms-dynamics-crm-add-on/

Let me know if I can help in any way.

Comment: I used the only plugin available at Codecanyon.net Gravity Forms CRM Addon

Comment: I understand. Our plugin is not available on Codecanyon.net. Our plugin is only available for purchase from our website at the link above.